# How to convert special symbols and characters in URL with web scraping? in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a URL contain Arabic characters:  [https://sa.aqar.fm/عقارات/1](https://sa.aqar.fm/%D8%B9%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA/1)

when I do web scraping, the Arabic characters convert to special symbols,
I doing Encoding `"UTF-8"` but it does not solve the problem

```
 #convert page number 1 to %d to get result from 1 to 5 page  " https://sa.aqar.fm/%D8%B9%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA/1" 

url_1 <- 'https://sa.aqar.fm/%D8%B9%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA/%d'
Encoding(url_1) <- "UTF-8"

df1 <- map_df(1:5, function(i) {
pg <- read_html(sprintf(url_1, i))

data.frame(Title=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".listTitle")),
         Price=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".price")),
         Address=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".details")),
         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  
 })
```

I get Error

```
Error in sprintf(url_1, i) : 
  invalid format '%D8%B9%D9%82%D8%A'; use format %d, %i, %o, %x or %X for integer objects
```

or when I write the Arabic word like the original link I get

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.
```

please can anyone help me?

Comment: iterate over five links?

Comment: Yes, actually it's the same link just I want to get the results from 5 pages

Comment: Its not same I think. First page : https://sa.aqar.fm/%D8%B9%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA/1
Second page : https://sa.aqar.fm/%D8%B9%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA/2

Change last number 1,2,3,4,5 as per your requirement.

Comment: I know, when I add %d instead of numbers the function work with me, the problem is these characters " %D8%B9%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%" in the link

Comment: you want results in arabic languge?

Comment: Yes, I tried many links and I get the data in Arabic but if links have the Arabic words I get these errors